# Python : get the text of an element when the parent contains a specific word

Tags: python, html, xpath, extract

I'm trying to find the text in a list (ul/li/text()) only when the parent (span) contains the word 'address:'.
I already did this :

```
address = response.xpath('//span[span[.="Address:"]]/ul//li//text()').extract()
```

but it doesn't work... maybe cause it means that span contains exactly 'Address:' and nothing else.

I haven't found anything that could help me...

Anyone? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function to match `span` by partial text content:

```
//span[span[contains(.,"Address:")]]/ul//li//text()
```